# JWPLAYER not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, sharepoint, internet-explorer-11, jwplayer

On a SharePoint 2010 website I'm using jwplayer for the streaming of some videos.

Below is the code I included in SharePoint:

```
<!-- JW Player Library -->
<script src="http://jwpsrv.com/library/MCK8hplLEeOY0CIACmOLpg.js"></script>

<div id='playerKXSDPIwKERSb'></div>

<!-- Script to display video file in the player div -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
    jwplayer('playerKXSDPIwKERSb').setup({
        // URL to the video file
        file: 'http://localhost/SiteAssets/Pages/testvideo/video.mp4',
        // URL to the image that should be shown before the video is started
        title: 'Video',
        width: '50%',
        aspectratio: '16:9'
    });
</script>
```

Is working perfect on Chrome and Edge but not working on IE11.

On the javascript console I obtain the following errors:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem and I want to share the solution.

I was using JWPLAYER inside SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint was providing a meta tag telling IE to behave like ie8. Since JWPlayer is not supporting ie8 anymore I was not able to reproduce the videos. I removed the meta tag and JWPlayer kept working.